# Build expression from object

Tags: c#, reflection, expression, entity-framework-plus

I have the following object received from Angular client application in ASP.NET Core:

```
public class ModelFromClient
{
  public string name {get;set;}      //Database field is Name
  public int qunatity {get;set;}     //Database field is Quantity
}
```

And I have a EF Table class:

```
[Table("MyTable")]
public class MyRow
{
  public int Id {get;set;}  
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Qunatity {get;set;}
}
```

Now I need to create expression from `ModelFromClient` to `Expression<Func<MyRow, MyRow>>` and I need it with generic.
Without generics solution would be:

```
public Expression<Func<MyRow, MyRow>> ToExpression(ModelFromClient Model)
{
    Expression<Func<MyRow, MyRow>> result = (t) => new MyRow()
    {
        Name = Model.name, 
        Quantity = Model.qunatity
    };
    return result;
}
```

But I would like something like that:

```
public Expression<Func<T, T>> ToExpression<T>(object Model) where T: new()
{
    Expression<Func<T, T>> result = (t) => new T();
    foreach(var prop in Model.GetType().GetProperties()) 
    {
       //compile error Fields does not exists.
       result.Body.Fields.Add(prop.Name.Capitalize(), prop.GetValue(Model, null));  //capitalize returns Name from input name
    }
    return result;
}
```

I need expression to pass it to [Update](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus#batch-update) extension method of EntityFramework-Plus.

Comment: Please post your solution in answer, not as an edit to the question to learn more see [tour]

Comment: If you feel that the existing answer is insufficient, and that you need to post your own answer, then post the solution *as an answer*, and not as an edit to the question.  The question is where you ask the question, not where you post solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](http://entityframework-plus.net/)

Here is a fiddle to get you started: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JY0wzw

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class Program
{
    public class MyRow
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Qunatity { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var type = typeof(MyRow);
        var constructorInfo = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
        var newExpression = Expression.New(constructorInfo);

        var memberInits = new List<MemberAssignment>();
        foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.Name == "Id")
            {
                memberInits.Add(Expression.Bind(prop, Expression.Constant(1)));
            }
            else if (prop.Name == "Name")
            {
                memberInits.Add(Expression.Bind(prop, Expression.Constant("Z_Name")));
            }
            else if (prop.Name == "Qunatity")
            {
                memberInits.Add(Expression.Bind(prop, Expression.Constant(2)));
            }
        }

        var expression = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, memberInits);

        // FOR testing purpose
        var compiledExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyRow>>(expression).Compile();
        var myRow = compiledExpression();

        Console.WriteLine(myRow.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(myRow.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(myRow.Qunatity);
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Eval-Expression.NET](http://eval-expression.net/)

This library is not free but allows you to create code dynamically at runtime. Once you get familiar, you can do pretty much anything you want way more easily than with the previous solution.

```
// Register your type
EvalManager.DefaultContext.RegisterType(typeof(MyRow));

// Register extension methods once from Z.EntityFramework.Plus
EvalManager.DefaultContext.RegisterExtensionMethod(typeof(BatchUpdate));

Eval.Execute("query.Update(x => new MyRow() { Id = 1, Name = 'Z_Name', Qunatity = 2});", new {query});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Jonathan Magnan said (thank you Jonathan), his answer point me to right direction:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, T>> ToExpressionGeneric<T>(this object Model) where T : new()
{
    var type = typeof(T);
    var constructorinfo = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);
    var newExpression = Expression.New(constructorinfo);

    var memberInits = new List<MemberAssignment>();

    var modelProperties = Model.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
    {
        var modelProperty = modelProperties.Where(t => t.Name == prop.Name.FirstLetterToLowerCase()).SingleOrDefault();
        if (modelProperty != null)
            memberInits.Add(Expression.Bind(prop, Expression.Constant(modelProperty.GetValue(Model, null))));
    }

    var expression = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, memberInits);

    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "p");

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(expression, p);
}

public static string FirstLetterToLowerCase(this string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        throw new ArgumentException("There is no first letter");

    char[] a = s.ToCharArray();
    a[0] = char.ToLower(a[0]);
    return new string(a);
}
```

Just in case if someone will search for same solution.