# Update entity from expression (EF Core 2.0)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

How can I update entity from expression?

I dynamically build which properties(columns) should be updated. Function that do that returns `Expression<Func<T, T>>` where `T` is `entity`.
I have loaded entity from database using `Where` and `Single`.

```
Expression<Func<T, T>> expr = this.CallVirtualMethodAndGetExpression(ModelFromRequest);
DbUser entity = this.context.Users.Where(t => t.Id == 1).Single();

some magic ???    //tried expr.Compile()(entity) but it does not work.

this.context.SaveChanges();

//use DbUser with updated properties of course.
```

I know I could use [EF Plus](https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus) (batch update), but I want to stick with `SaveChanges` (I need `DbUser` after `SaveChanges` and I want to avoid sending another request).

**Updated:**
I have entity object and expression. Now, I need to edit entity object based on expression and called `SaveChanges` which should update entity.

Comment: A bounty doesn't make a question answerable. It's absolutely unclear what you're trying to achieve. You could start by showing the attempt you refer to in the comment.

Comment: I add additional information in question. I believe my code with additional explanation explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: If the expression you are talking about is coming from this question by you [Build expression from object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468652/build-expression-from-object), and in general `Expression<Func<T, T>>`, then it's absolutely inappropriate for *updating*. For updating you need `Expression<Action<T, T>>` which does not use `new { ... }` (`Expression.MemberInit`) but block of assignments. The way currently formulated, the question makes no any sense.

Comment: After your update: well, there's zero new info in there. Maybe you should tell why simply setting values in a `User` object isn't enough. I think that creating the expression takes at least the same amount of code.

Answer (score 2):

the magic line you are looking for:

```
var resultOfTypeT = expr.Compile().Invoke(entity)
```

But then `entity` needs to be an instance of type `T` , not `DbUser`
So this does not make sense to me.
So i cant give you exact code to compile for you, since i cant see the method signature where `T` is defined. and also do not know what the method signature of `this.CallVirtualMethodAndGetExpression(ModelFromRequest)` looks like.

But the `Compile()` will change the `Expression<Func<T,T>>` to just `Func<T,T>` which can then `Invoke` the defined functionality for `Func<T,T>` if you have a valid instance of `T` to pass to it.

Now your `entity` is not of type `T`, since it is of type `DbUser` So you are probably going to need to change your Method Signature or get your DbUser in a generic way or something. If you are only going to need to pass a `DbUser` instance, you do not need c# Generics. but cant really tell with just the current information available.